# typescript enum extend undefined value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend an existing enum in typescript. It's look like working when typing but value for extended enum member is undefined.

**I'm using node.js 8.0.0 with tsc 2.4.2**

--- ecategorytype.ts ---

```
export enum eCategoryType {
    generic = 'generic',

    resources = 'resources',
    friendGroup = 'friendGroup'
}
```

--- enumextend.ts ---

```
import eCategoryType from './ecategorytype';

declare module './ecategorytype' {
    export enum eCategoryType {
        classGroup = 'classGroup',
        testGroup = 'testGroup'
    }
}
```

--- usage ---

```
import eCategoryType from '../models/category/ecategorytype';
import '../models/category/enumextend';
console.log(eCategoryType.friendGroup);
console.log(eCategoryType.classGroup);
console.log(eCategoryType.testGroup);
```

--- enumextend.d.ts ---

```
declare module './ecategorytype' {
    enum eCategoryType {
        classGroup = "classGroup",
        testGroup = "testGroup",
    }
}
export {};
```

--- enumextend.js ---

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
//# sourceMappingURL=typeext.js.map
```

--- expected console output ----

```
friendGroup
testGroup
classGroup
```

--- reality console output ---

```
friendGroup
undefined
undefined
```

---

What could be wrong please?

Comment: Where do you import `enumextend.ts`?

Comment: Updated: I tried to call: import '../models/category/enumextend' in usage but still same result.

Comment: `import '../models/category/enumextend';` --- what does this import supposed to do? You run it but don't use any exported identifiers.

Comment: error TS2305: Module '"src/models/category/enumextend"' has no exported member 'eCategoryType'. if I call import {eCategoryType} from '../models/category/enumextend';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: extending imported enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940349/typescript-extending-imported-enum)

Answer (score 0):

You import is wrong:

```
import eCategoryType from '../models/category/ecategorytype';
```

Should be:

```
import {eCategoryType} from '../models/category/ecategorytype';
```